# SAS Proc Import Specific Range from xlsm file

Tags: import, sas

I'm in the need of importing an xlsm file and pulling just one cell value from a specific spreadsheet.

I've tried using the below but get a 'CLI error trying to establish connection' error. I do have to use the rsubmit blocks. What am I doing wrong?

```
RSUBMIT INHERITLIB=(mywork);
OPTIONS msglevel=i VALIDVARNAME= any;

proc import datafile="\\mysite.com\folder1\folder2\myfile.xlsm"
dbms=EXCELCS replace out=Output;
range="EmailSummary$O5";
run;

ENDRSUBMIT;
```

Comment: You question seems to more about accessing a remote file rather than accessing a specific cell in the file. Isn't the file local to where SAS is running? Do you really have to use PCFILES server to access the file?  Do you really have to use a remote SAS session to access the PCFILES server?  Can you just use the XLSX engine instead of the EXCELCS engine?  Can you access the full sheet if you use the SHEET statement instead of the RANGE statement?

Comment: File is not local, it is on a shared drive.  I don't necessarily need the EXCELCS engine. I was using that due to an article i found stating it needed to be used with xlsm. I changed it back to xlsx and the import for the entire sheet works. However I still cannot get the specific cell range to import only

Comment: Are you trying to access a named range? Or the cell 05 in the sheet named EmalSummary?

Comment: Thanks as always for your help. Changing back to XLSX worked. Is there a way to assign a variable name to the value that is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import only one cell then you need to tell IMPORT not to look for names and also give it both the upper left and lower right cell of the range.

```
  getnames=no;
  range="EmailSummary$O5:O5";
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign a variable name to the value that is returned

Comment: Use the RENAME= dataset option on the output dataset.  `out=Output(rename=(A=NewName))`